# Why does kpartx use a new loop device each time?

Tags: ubuntu, python, devices, loop-device, disk-image

I'm running `kpartx` from within a python script as part of a custom OS build I'm trying to do. I'm using python `sh` module to run bash commands.

`sh.kpartx("-as", image)` is how I attach my image.

Then I create partitions and a file system on each partition. Then ofcourse I unmount the image.

`sh.kpartx("-d", image)`

The problem is that in my script I use the above attach and detach commands a couple of times and with each time a new `/dev/loopX` is used. I would expect that after I detach an image from let's say `/dev/loop0` on the next attachment I would be able to use it again. This is not the case however and `/dev/loop1` is used.

What is going on and why?

Comment: Where is this `sh.kpartx` method coming from? I don't see it in my `sh` module and I don't see it mentioned in [the sh documentation](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/).

Comment: You can substitute any command you want after sh._____

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `kpartx` stores no state, so it doesn't remember whether you originally called in on `/dev/loop0`, or whether it had to set up the loop device.

Going from the examples in it's `man` page, `losetup` is pretty scriptable, so it shouldn't be too much extra work to handle that part yourself.